# Verify SQL has executed correctly in WebMatrix/Razor?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, webmatrix

I am trying to verify if my SQL has been executed correctly, and if not return an error.

My code :

```
 var db = Database.Open("database");
            db.Execute("INSERT INTO Users(Username, Email, FirstName, SecondName) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", username, email, firstName, secondName);
```

Also, how can you mark a column as unique using WebMatrix? This seems to be a pretty basic functionality that I am really missing! I want to make it so that emails and usernames must be unique, but I cannot see any way to do this? I am essentially then hoping to test if the INSERT INTO can be executed (i.e there is no email/username the same already existing in the database).

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question:

The `Execute` method returns the number of affected records, and your code snip is doing an insert so if it fails it'll return a value that isn't equal to 1.

```
var db = Database.Open("database");
if (db.Execute("INSERT INTO Users(Username, Email, FirstName, SecondName) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", username, email, firstName, secondName) < 1)
   throw new Exception("Wasn't able to insert User record");
```

The second, I'm not sure about but it should probably be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored procedure that conditionally adds the new user and returns a row count (0 if the user already exists):

```
create procedure dbo.AddUser
    @username varchar(80)
    , @email varchar(128)
    , @firstname varchar(128)
    , @secondname varchar(128)
as
    insert into [Users] (Username,Email,FirstName,SecondName)
    select @username, @email, @firstname, @secondname
    where not exists(
        select 1 from [Users] (nolock)
        where Username=@username
        and Email=@email
    )
    return @@rowcount
go
```

Calling from C#:

```
var db = Database.Open("database");
if (db.Execute("dbo.AddUser @username=?, @email=?, @firstname=?, @secondname=?", username, email, firstName, secondName) < 1)
   throw new Exception("Wasn't able to insert User record");
```